# Error in running WhiteboxTools in command line

Tags: whitebox-tools

I am trying to perform IDW interpolation in WhiteboxTools in my LAS files to create raster image through command line:

```
C:\WhiteboxTools_win_amd64\WBT>whitebox_tools -r=LidarIdwInterpolation -v ^
More? -wd = "E:/Processed_lidar/norm_thinned_01m/norm_thinned_01m/" -i=GO72A-3.las -o=idw.tif ^
More? --resolution=0.1 --weight= 2.0 --radius=0.3"
```

And getting following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error parsing -weight: ParseFloatError { kind: Empty }', src\tools\lidar_analysis\lidar_idw_interpolation.rs:326:26
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I am using windows 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are having a parsing error on the weight parameter, which I suspect is the result of the space that you have present in "--weight= 2.0". Try using "--weight=2.0" instead.